# In MongoDB, how can I find documents whose id are in a array field of other documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have these documents in the collection "banks". The "accounts" array store the ID's of the accounts linked to each bank.

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "city" : "Madrid",
    "accounts" : [ 
        "1", 
        "2", 
        "3", 
        "4", 
        "5", 
        "6"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "city" : "Berlin",
    "accounts" : [ 
        "7", 
        "8"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "city" : "Madrid",
    "accounts" : [ 
        "9", 
        "10", 
        "11", 
        "12"
    ]
}
```

And collection "accounts" goes like this:

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "owner" : "Antonio"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "owner" : "Pedro"
}

/* etc, up to 12 accounts */
```

I want to find all the accounts that are in any bank located in "Madrid" (I should get all accounts but 7 and 8)
I believe the first step is to create an array of the banks located in Madrid like this:

```
banksInMadrid = db.banks.find({ city: "Madrid"}).toArray()
```

But I have no clue on what to do next.

Thank you.

Edit: I'm using MongoDB 3.2

Comment: What is your expected output format?

Comment: @DheemanthBhat I want to output a standard print of the accounts linked to any bank in "Madrid", just like if I did db.accounts.find(), but just getting the correct accounts

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we need data from two or more collections we perform `$lookup` inside an `aggregation` pipeline. [Read this doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) and try this:

```js
db.accounts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "banks",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "accounts",
            as: "banks"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$banks" },
    {
        $match: { "banks.city": "Madrid" }
    },
    {
        $project: { banks: 0 }
    }
]);
```

output:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "owner" : "Antonio"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "owner" : "Pedro"
}
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, however I'm using mongoDB 3.2 and I believe that this doesn't work there, I'm getting an error. Thanks for you help anyways

Comment: assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { account_id: \"$accounts\" } is type 3",
 "code" : 4570
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Check the updated answer that works for 3.2

Comment: I'm getting another error: assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion",
 "code" : 16406
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it using the array of banks from Madrid? Like this: banksInMadrid = db.banks.find({ city: "Madrid"}).toArray()

Comment: The error is because of the `$project` stage. You can remove it. and neglect the `banks` object in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find into sub documents like:

```
db.banks.find( { "accounts._id": 2 )
```

Check this for more information:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/